# wildfly - Application not reached

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, wildfly

I'm woking on Java project. I use Maven, Wildfly and IntelliJ IDEA, running on Ubuntu 16.04. I've created a simple Hello-world application in Main class, using `System.out.println()` . I'm trying to deploy it on Wildfly server. What I'm doing is:
1. Run standalone.sh
2. Deploy project from it's folder.

Now, as far as I understand, I should see the result, if I type localhost:8080/'Project name'. But when I follow the link, i get Error 404. 
Should I use any other tools? 
Or how the application should be structered in order to be deployable on Wildfly server? 
Here's my `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SI</groupId>
    <artifactId>Navrh</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-javaee7-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>10.1.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you're deploying the application?

Comment: Please show the output of the console log when you deploy your project. Does it contain a line containing `WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /Project name`?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Ok. I start standalone.sh, then test connection to database in admin console. After that, terminal to project folder, and deploy it with `mvn clean package wildfly:deploy`. Also, I added @Entity annotation to my Main class, but no changes.

Comment: @SteveC yes, it does

Comment: Next notice is when i type localhost:8080/'Project name', i get Forbidden message.

Comment: Given the configuration your app should be available at `localhost:8080/Navrh`. Note though that assumes you have some kind of `index.html` or `index.jsp`.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your "Main" class, but using System.out.println() in this context doesn't make sense to me. What are you using for printing "helloworld", servlet, jsp, jsf...?